# Missing a [ptfe-tube] or [bowden-tube] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I just created [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/how-to-straighten-ptfe-tubes), but there was a surprising lack of relevant tags. I don't have the privileges to add new ones myself, so could someone create some appropriate tag(s) for this?

(PS: I flagged my own question earlier to make this same request. That was before I remembered about meta. Sorry.)

Comment: Looks like there are tags for Bowden and PTEF tube

Comment: @StarWind: There are now. They were added yesterday.